# Clojure 1.10.0 in Apache Storm 1.2.3

Tags: maven, clojure, apache-storm

I'm using apache storm 1.2.3, which uses Clojure 1.7.0. I'm running topology written in Java that calls some Clojure code and I want to use features from Clojure 1.10.0 there.

I've added 1.10.0 version to pom.xml and I've tried adding 1.10.0 artifact using `--artifacts` option for `storm jar`

`storm jar ... --artifacts "org.clojure:clojure:1.10.0"`

After deploying the topology the artifact is resolved successfully but when running the code, I keep getting errors from 1.7.0 jar. Is there any way to override this dependency without upgrading storm to 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to replace the clojure 1.7.0 jar in the storm /lib directory with the 1.10 jar. When we upgraded to Clojure 1.10, there were no source changes https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/2976/files.

I can't promise this will work, as the Storm 1.x branch has a lot more Clojure code than 2.x. If it doesn't work, you will probably need to upgrade to 2.x.